# I Forgot What Twitter Account I Registered API App In - How Can I Find Out?

Tags: twitter

I registered a Twitter API app, and it works fine.  I have just one little problem:  I can't remember what Twitter account I was logged into when I created it.

I tried to re-register the same app in another Twitter account, but Twitter seems to be rejecting it because the "Application Website" is already used, and Twitter won't let me leave that field blank,

Any idea how I can find out what Twitter account I was in when I registered the app?

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 0):

For [single-user use cases](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token), if you look at the value of the OAuth access token, it will have the form:

```
nnnnnnn-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

where `n` is a decimal number, and `x` is a base64-encoded character.  The decimal portion of the access token, up to the hyphen, is the Twitter user ID that the app was registered under.  To get the actual user info, run the following query (substituting the number from your access token for the `nnnnnnnnn` below.)

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?user_id=nnnnnnnnn
```

This may hold in multiple user scenarios as well.